# I have Created a Web API but when i call it in controller then it always gives same StatusCode i.e "OK"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

My API Code is given below where we create login api:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILogWrapper Log = LogManagerWrapper.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage.</returns>
    /// 
    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage.</returns>
    /// 
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string email,string password,bool remember)
    {
        var result = SignInStatus.Failure;
        try
        {
            result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, remember, shouldLockout: false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error in login = " + ex.Message, ex);

        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
}
```

And Controller code is :

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var code = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:52958/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            var res = await client.GetAsync("api/Account/Get?email=" + model.UserName + "&password=" + model.Password + "&remember=" + model.RememberMe + "");
            code = res.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        switch (code)
        {
            case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

When I execute this API through swagger then it respose very well it always show success if authentication detail is right else it give Failure But when i call this API through controller then I get always status is OK. How I get The correct Status code?

Comment: In your account controller you have the only return hard coded to return httpstatus code OK even if it fails or succeeds.  You would need to move the return you have inside the try, and in the catch add an additional return that uses the status code you want for when an Error Occurs.  Which I would suggest you do some parsing of your error message or have your signinmanager return something vs throwing for accounts that are not correct or don't exist you would want a 401, if its truly an error you would want to return 500.

Comment: Yes, I also notice it always return OK that's because of I return  HttpStatusCode.OK in hard coded. I try to resolve it but didn't understand it return exact  HttpStatusCode to controller

Answer (score 0):

It *should* be returning 200 OK. In your switch statement based on the status code returned from the Web Api request, if 200 was returned, then you do a temporary redirect. A temporary redirect is actually a 301, but the web browser responds by issuing a new request for the URL in the redirect, and the response from that request (given everything goes right) will be a 200.

In the case your Web Api returns an error status code, you're returning a view, which is going to produce a 200 (again assuming everything goes right with returning that view).

This is actually the way it should be. The fact that your Web Api failed should not propagate into your MVC response. From the user's perspective, they are either being redirected or returned to the previous view with an error message. That is ideal. You wouldn't want to return a 500 to the user because the Web Api returned a 500. Then the user is stuck at an error page. Instead, you gracefully recover, deliver a response to the user (as a 200) that includes a message saying that their request couldn't be processed, try again later, etc. In other words, you explain what went wrong, but you're still delivering a successful response to the user.

It's really two different things. Delivering a successful response to the user doesn't mean that everything happened as it should. It just means that the browser has something it can work with, something it can present to the user. In this scenario, that's what you want, because the user needs to be informed about what happened, have the ability to fix their mistakes, etc.

Comment: It's Always return 200 when i use actual authentication or I use wrong authentication and it got logged in. How i prevent it when I feed wrong authentication then it should not logged in?

Comment: I see nothing where you're actually doing any sort of sign in. You're just fetching a user from the Web Api. If that's successful, you're redirecting, and if not, you're returning an error message. It looks like your Web Api action may be performing a sign in, but that's actually wrong. Web Api has no access to `Session` which is very much necessary to actually have someone be "logged in". Further, even if you did have access, it would be setting it for that Web Api, not your MVC site. Instead, your Web Api should merely return whether or not the sign in info checks out.

Comment: Then, your MVC action should sign the user in if there is a "true" response, or return with an error if there's a "false" response. Not that it needs to be a boolean; it's just however you're determining the truthiness.